# How do I run a python program in a virtual environment from windows command prompt?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, virtual-environment

I created a virtual environment for a Python program using PyCharm. I can run the program just fine straight from PyCharm terminal but when I try to run it from windows command prompt I get an error because some modules in the program are only installed in the virtual environment.

So my question is: how do I run a Python program that is in a virtual environment from the command prompt?

Comment: You have to activate environment in terminal first using `env\scripts\activate.bat` command

Comment: Ahh thank you! It worked!

I'm very new to this so I'm still learning the basics

Answer (score 7):

```
$ cd your_project
$ ./activate.bat
$ python helloworld.py
```

Explaination: virtualenv should create a .bat file in your project root directory. To run it, activate the virtual env first then run the python command.

Comment: venv activation is a convenience for interactive work. It sets the venv's "bin" (Unix) or "Scripts" (Windows) directory at the start of `PATH` and also sets the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable (which py.exe in Windows looks for in some cases). But if you explicitly run the qualified path of "python[.exe]" in the venv, you do not need to activate it. In particular, in Windows if the py launcher is installed an associated with .py files, you can run a script directly that uses the qualified path of the venv python.exe in its shebang line (e.g. `#!"C:\venv\someenv\Scripts\python.exe"`).

Comment: @ErykSun This is great, thanks! The shebang can even be relative: `#!".venv\Scripts\python.exe"`.